# Delete Firestore indexes programmatically/CLI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

It's possible to deploy indexes from the CLI using `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`.

But is it possible to delete them using the CLI or via a client of some kind?

I can't see any reference to it in the CLI docs. And while there does seem to be a REST endpoint for it [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.indexes/delete), I'd have to write a client to call it.

Seems pretty clunky to force the user to go into the console UI and manually click on 'delete' for every index they want to remove. Especially because during development these indexes may change frequently.

Comment: What if you deploy indexes using the CLI that don't include the one you want to delete?

Comment: @DougStevenson it just gives me the warning `there are some indexes defined in your project that are not present in your firestore indexes file. Run firebase firestore:indexes and save the result to correct the discrepancy`

Comment: OK, this sounds like a feature request that you should file.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Seems that now the CLI will prompt you to delete indexes that exist remotely but are not defined in firestore.indexes.json.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

I've submitted a feature request, but as of now (Jan 29, 2019) it's not possible to do this via the CLI.

To quote the response I received:

> This is definitely a highly requested feature, but there's no telling on when it will be implemented. You can keep an eye on the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) to be informed of the latest from Firebase.